# How do I make water that can't flow for adventure maps?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to build a race for the wool style map, and I've seen tons of other maps in versions all the way up to 1.16 that have underwater sections without walls to hold the water in. I know they aren't using barriers, because they can still fire arrows into the water, and they aren't using a fill command, because that isn't fast enough to stop the water. As well as that, it's entirely in vanilla, since I can download the map and play it and not have any problems on a vanilla profile. So how do they do it? I do have world edit at my disposal if the solution requires it.
[image]

Comment: im pretty sure `//fill`ing with air should just do that

Comment: I tried exactly that earlier and the water just flows back into the spot I filled. And when I put that in to a repeating command block, it's not fast enough to prevent the water from flowing out a bit

Comment: Use `/setblock <x y z> water`.

Comment: That doesn't work, the water automatically updates.

Comment: @JohnKlubertanz just to be clear, you did `//fill` like the world edit command and not `/fill` like the minecraft command, right?

Comment: Re "it's entirely in Vanilla": Once the blocks that border the water have been removed without updating the water (which doesn't need to be a Vanilla capability), it will remain afloat like this until it's updated by something else. Also, I'm pretty sure nonexistant blocks are removed without causing block updates.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Place structure void blocks around spaces you don't want the water flowing into.

To get a structure void, use this command:

```
give @s minecraft:structure_void 1
```

The structure void's hitbox is a small cube in the middle of the block that can be broken to turn the block into air. Water will never flow into its space while it is active.

Comment: Oh my god. I can't believe I completely forgot about structure voids! Thank you for reminding me, you're the best!